# Sidebar menu with indicate navigationbar on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller

I want to create sidebar menu with indicate `UINavigationBar` like below mention image.

[image]

By using `ECSlidingviewController` library i have done side menu. But thing is i need to display `Navigation` `Indicator` when user slide on menu.

How can i create? Any one having idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special to do here. 
Simply create your view and add it as a subview of the navigationBar in your controller (not the menu controller).

Here is a simple demonstration:

```
CGFloat desiredWidth = x;<----replace x.
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-desiredWidth,0,desiredWidth,44)];
[testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:testView];
```